# Relación de 2 ComboBox

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, combobox

Quiero hacer dos `combobox` relacionados.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Marca de la computadora
2. Modelo de la computadora

Cuando escoja el primer combobox `marca` que en el segundo, me muestre los `modelo` de esa marca. Un filtrado de información típico. Como el de `país` y `estado`.

Escoger la `marca` y que SOLAMENTE me de, los `modelos` de esa computadora.

Tengo dos ideas MYSQL:

1. Crear una tabla de `DELL` (marca) y meter todos los modelos de `DELL`, crear otra tabla `HP`, otra tabla `GATEWAY`, etc.
2. Crear una tabla donde voy a meter DELL, HP, TOSHIBA etc, con sus correspondientes modelos.

Formulario con su base de datos. Solo que no sé por donde empezar, y que sea beneficioso a la larga, que ya las tablas se van a estar actualizando constantemente. (Perdon por escribir mucho).

Comment: Hola. que tienen que ver todos los tags que escribiste? es una pregunta que se acerca a ser basada en opiones.. sin embargo mas allá de darte una respuesta te daría una recomendación, lee sobre base de datos y normalizacion... (la opción 1 es un no!, la 2 va por el camino correcto, casi.)

Comment: Perdón si meto muchos tags, soy algo nuevo en esto, solo lo hice para resaltar algunas palabras claves.

Comment: si lo se. pero la pregunta es solamente sobre base de datos, el resto solo confunde y puede llevar a que voten negativamente a tu pregunta.

Comment: Soy nueva en esto de programación y me gustaría entender mejor esto de los combobox, tengo exactamente el mismo problema, en un combobox tengo tipos de aparatos como computadoras, celulares, etc, al momento de seleccionar computadora quiero que me aparezcan las marcas de esas computadoras, me podrían ayudar!
GRACIAS!

Comment: Hola @Dairy, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Si tienes una pregunta parecida, crea tu propia publicación en lugar escribirla en una respuesta. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] y que leas [ask] en el centro de ayuda. También te comento que ya se han hecho varias preguntas sobre este mismo tema, realiza una búsqueda en el sitio y podrás encontrarlas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas crear dos tablas: Marca y Modelo, en la tabla de modelo necesitas tener una relación con la tabla marca, por ejemplo el ID del registro que identifica a una marca, para que sepas que ese modelo pertenece a esa marca.

Ejemplos.

Tabla Marca:

- id_marca
- nombre_marca
- ..

Tabla Modelo:

- id_modelo
- id_marca
- nombre_modelo

Entonces para llenar el "combobox" de marcas haces el siguiente select:

```
select id_marca, nombre_marca 
from Marca
```

Y para el combobox de modelo usas el siguiente select:

```
select id_modelo, nombre_modelo 
from Modelo
where id_marca = {aquí le pasas el id de la marca que elijan en el combobox de marcas}
```

Entonces para poder hacer un combobox relacionado necesitarás utilizar jquery o ajax para realizar el query de los modelos al seleccionar una marca.

Ejemplo de una llama a php desde ajax:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'mi_pagina.com/archivo.php',
         data: {id_marca: 'test'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      //aquí procesamos la data retornada por el archivo php
                  }
});
```

Entonces en tu archivo.php realizas el query a la tabla de modelos y lo devuelves para que sea procesado en el método success de la llamada ajax, si los datos fueron retornados correctamente llenas el combobox de modelos.

Esto es un tema mucho mas extenso, pero espero haberte ayudado en algo.

Te dejo un link con un articulo en ingles:

http://www.codingcage.com/2015/04/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-php.html

Saludos.